# MatDatepicker max attribute not working when setting value dynamically

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I'm working on an Ionic-Angular project with Ionic v4. I tried the max attr in input tag of matdatepicker. Its working when the value is blank. But when I set value in input programmatically, the max validation does not work. I tied setting the value using ngModel, formcontrol and formcontrolname. But each time max attr did not worked.

```css
<mat-form-field class="full-width">
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" readonly placeholder="Date Performed" [max]="todayDate" (click)="picker.open()"
            [formControl]="serializedDate" formControlName="selecteddate">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
          </mat-form-field>
```

```html
let convetedDate = moment('1544466600000', "x").format("DD-MMM-YYYY");
    this.myDate = new Date(Date.parse(convetedDate));
    this.serializedDate = new FormControl(this.myDate);
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are binding `todayDate` as `[max]` for the date picker, your `todayDate` variable should contain the maximum date. It cant be set using either ngModel or formControl.
I have created a stackblitz using your example in which i set the `todayDate` variable in the logic and it is working as expected. [Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxqsdy-wanoi3?file=app%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.ts)
Hope this helps

**Edit:** `[max]` is still working after setting the value of `serializedDate` either using `ngModel` or `[formControl]`. See updated stackblitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mxqsdy-wanoi3?file=app%2Fdatepicker-min-max-example.ts)

I think why you are not able to see the max in action in the date picker is because the date you are setting for the date control is 12/10/2018 while the `max` is set to today's date. So try navigating to the current month and you will see the disabled dates after today's date as in the stackblizt.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I might have forgotten to add `this.todayDate=new Date();` in my above code snippet. But its there. Code is working if there is no value in datepicker. It does not work when I set value to the datepicker. Have you tried setting its value `serializedDate` or `selecteddate`?